# OpenGl GluLookAt to GlRotated and GlTranslated

Tags: opengl

I dont understand how this GluLookAt works in OpenGl.

I would like to know how to transform this two lines :

```
gluLookAt(5.0, 15.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
gluLookAt(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
```

using glRotatef and glTranslatef.

After some searches, it seems to exist a way for making that thing :

```
glRotatef();
glRotatef();
glTranslatef(5.0,15.0,2.0);

glRotatef();
glRotatef();
glTranslatef(5.0,0.0,5.0);
```

So just by using two rotations and one translation.
But I dont understand how can i find the angles and the axes of these rotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to explain how the functions work below. Hope it makes you understand the concept. For rotation and translation you can check [this link](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/keyboard-example-moving-around-the-world/)  to see how it is handled.

```
 struct Triple
 {
    float x,y,z;
 }


 //CameraPosition
 Triple Cp(a,b,c); //initialise your camera position
 //LookatPosition
 Triple Lp(e,f,g); //initialise your lookat position
 //Up vector
 Triple Up(k,l,m); //initialise your up vector 



UpdateCamera()
{
    //Update Cp, Lp here
    //if you move your camera use translatef to update camera position
    //if you want to change looking direction use correct rotation and translation to update your lookat position 

    //if you need to change up vector simply change it to
    Up = Triple(knew,lnew,mnew); 
}

display()
{
       gluLookAt(Cp.x,Cp.y,Cp.z,Lp.x,Lp.y,Lp.z,Up.x,Up.y,Up.z);

          //Your object drawings Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to sidestep the glRotate and glTranslate and use glLoadMatrix instead (glLoadMatrix replaces the current matrix on the stack use glMultMatrix if you want to multiply): you would then use an array of floats containing the matrix in column major order:

```
xaxis.x              yaxis.x           zaxis.x           0
xaxis.y              yaxis.y           zaxis.y           0
xaxis.z              yaxis.z           zaxis.z           0
-dot(xaxis, camP)  -dot(yaxis, camP)  -dot(zaxis, camP)  1
```

where

```
zaxis = normal(At - camP)
xaxis = normal(cross(Up, zaxis))
yaxis = cross(zaxis, xaxis)
```

and camP the position of the camera, At the point the camera is looking at and Up the up-vector.

Comment: Ty for your answer hakononakani but I have to do the thing with glRotate and glTranslate. I cannot use anything else :/

Comment: It likes a condition I cannot break :( But the next time I have to do the same thing, I think your solution is a good one. However, here it's not what I'm looking for. I have to use just glRotate and glTranslate for doing the job.

Comment: I don't see a reason to do this except for an exercise task and I won't do your homework for you :). If you still insist have a look at the opengl reverence pages (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) theres code that is very close to copy-pasteable.